# LongTimeString has deprecated? C# IValueConverter

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

I'm working on Universal Store app. I've made this converter:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
{
    string stringDate = (string)value;
    IFormatProvider culture = new CultureInfo( language );
    DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(stringDate, culture);
    return date.LongTimeString();
}
```

but Method LongTimeString is not recognized. This method is deprecated? Any solution? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`DateTime` doesn't have a method as `LongTimeString`. I think you looking for [`ToLongTimeString` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tolongtimestring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

```
return date.ToLongTimeString();
```

Mabe you are mixing this method with [`LongTimePattern` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.longtimepattern(v=vs.110).aspx) of `DateTimeFormatInfo`.

Comment: I've tried return date.ToLongTimeString();
But still not working. Visual Studio tell me: DateTime have not definition of method ToLongTimeString();

Answer (score 1):

It's not deprecated, just not part of the WinRT API.

The solution is something like

```
 return date.ToString("D");
```

But I'm not sure what exactly is supported.

Comment: Well, do you want "a long date" as defined by the current culture or do you have a specific format in mind?

Comment: Then document "not the same result". In the question, not in comments.